# Error codes and message handling in a plugin system

Tags: c, plugins, error-code

I am brooding over the best design of error codes and the corresponding error messages in a C project. This project consists of a small kernel providing the core functionality, which can be extended by various plugins. The kernel already defines the most general error codes, e.g. PROJ_NOERR (no error) or PROJ_ENOMEM (no memory available). Furthermore, the plugins should also be able to define special error codes and their corresponding messages, e.g. a web server plugin can define WEBSERV_ESOCKET (socket error). In my thoughts, the kernel should also provide a function for the translation of error codes to their corresponding error message, e.g. extern char* proj_err2str(enum err_t); This function should also be able to handle the defined error codes of all loaded plugins. How would you implement such a system? Any hints are welcome!

Thanks in advance,
/* Jonas */

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you mean, but here a sample code on how you can create your plugins:

```
/* This struct  is common to all plugins and the functions defined here must be implemented by all plugins*/
typedef struct
{
  int (*plugin_function_one) (char *str);
  void (*plugin_function_two) (int fd);
  void (*plugin_handle_error) (char *err, int status);
  char plugin_errors_codes[ERR_CODES_NUM]; // Each plugin can add errors code here
} plugin_t;
```

You can then create a plugin (plugin_one) for example like this:

```
int plugin_function_one(char *str)
{
    // Body of function_one
}

void plugin_function_two(int fd)
{
    Body of function_two
}

// Here you have your error handling function for plugin_one

void plugin_handle_error(char *err, int status)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Plugin --> Got this error: %s and errno = %d", strerror(err), errno);
    // depend on status, we can exist or not for exampe
    if (status)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Now init your plugin:

```
plugin_t * plugin_init (plugin_t * p)
{
  /* Plugin init */
  p-> plugin_function_one = plugin_function_one;
  p-> plugin_function_two = plugin_function_two;
  p-> plugin_handle_error = plugin_handle_error;

  /* init the array of errors here */
  init_plugin_errors(p->plugin_errors_codes);
  /* return the newly created plugin */
  return (p);
}
```

You can load and upload all your plugins like this:

```
int plugin_load (char *path_to_your_plugin)
{
    void *dh;
    plugin_t *(*p_init) (plugin_t * p);
    plugin_t dp;

    /* opening plugin */
    dh = dlopen (path_to_your_plugin, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (NULL == dh)
    {
        fprintf (stderr,  "Failed to load '%s' (errno=%d, msg='%s')\n",path_to_your_plugin, errno, strerror (errno));
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    /* Now we look for plugin_init function */
     p_init = dlsym (dh, "plugin_init");
    if (NULL == p_init)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Failed to get 'plugin_init'\n");
            dlclose (dh);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    /* We init the plugin */
    if (NULL == p_init (&dp))
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error plugin_init()\n");
            dlclose (dh);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    …..

    /* Calling plugin functions */
    dp.plugin_handle_error(char *err, int status);
}
```

And to unload the plugin:

```
int plugin_unload (char * path_to_your_plugin)
{
    /* Need the address of the loaded plugin to call dlclose, let's call it the_address */
    if (the_adress != NULL)
        fprintf(stdout, "This plugin will be unloaded : %p", the_adress);
    /* close plugin. */
    dlclose (the_adress);

    return 0;
}
```

To handle duplicate errors codes among different plugins, the function err2str need to know which plugin is submitting the request:

```
int err2str (plugin_t *plugin, int error_code)
{
    // Lookup in the plugin_errors_codes array
    char *my_error;
    my_error = error_lookup(plugin->plugin_errors_codes, error_code);
    print_error(my_error); 
}
```

Hope this help.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. My question was not about the plugin manager but was targeting the error handling functionality. I want that plugins can define their own error codes which are unique amongst the whole application (kernel and plugins). Furthermore I want a single function within the kernel (err2str) that can handle all defined error codes, also the ones defined by plugins.

Best regards!

Comment: @Jonas : For the error codes, you can create an array that will hold all error codes in the struct plugin, each plugin can init this array with his error codes. I will edit my answer to meet this.

Comment: Hmmm, but in this case two error codes defined by two different plugins can have the same error code value (int). Or did I understand something wrong? I think each error code should be unique among all plugins.

Comment: But maybe my thoughts/imagination are just senseless... I am not sure right now...

Comment: @Jonas : it depend on you, you can make all errors code uniq among all plugins it's much clear or each plugin can add it's errors codes and in this case, the function err2str need to know which plugin is calling and it can refer to it's code array as in the struct i show you. I will edit answer to add this.